# map is not a function when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of links that I render on a page. I created a function that changes a specific prop from `false` to `true` depending if the link is active or not. This is triggered on click.

When I view the result of the new set of links I can see that the active prop has changed but the rendering stops working.

code:

The links:

```
const links: Array<LinkObj> = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'A',
    icon: 'fa-chair',
    active: true,
    path: routePoints.A,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'P',
    icon: 'fa-info-circle',
    active: false,
    path: routePoints.p,
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'H',
    icon: 'fa-h-square',
    active: false,
    path: routePoints.O,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'U',
    icon: 'fa-h-square',
    active: false,
    path: routePoints.P,
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    text: 'UP',
    icon: 'fa-h-square',
    active: false,
    path: routePoints.PT,
  },
];
```

inside of the render:

```
const [linksToRender, setlinksToRender] = useState(links);

 const navLinkClicked = (event: any, obj: LinkObj, path: string) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newLinks = linksToRender.map(link => {
      if (link.id === obj.id) link.active = true;
      else link.active = false;

      return link;
    });

    console.log('NEW L', newLinks);

    setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ({ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks }));
  };
```

After the last line where I update the links the page turns red and I get:

> TypeError: linksToRender.map is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: linksToRender is not an Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call you should just pass the new array to it:

```
setlinksToRender(newLinks);
```

Also please notice that if you do this:

```
setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ([ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks ]));
```

You will be **adding** `newLinks` to the `prevLinks` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Seems obvious now, been working in a diffirent scenario  for some time where I needed to take into account the previouse state.. thx for this

Answer (score 2):

- When you call `setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ({ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks }));` on `navLinkClicked`, the state `linksToRender` becomes an object.
- Change `setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ({ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks }));` to `setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ([ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks ]));`

Comment: Thx alot m8, this works! Accepting other answer since it is simpler, great job anyways and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should understand one thing about spread operator `...`

Spread operator just create a new copy of the existing memory item (array/object).
So, here you should change

```
setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ({ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks }));
```

to

```
setlinksToRender(prevLinks => ([ ...prevLinks, ...newLinks ]));
```

to create a new array, by combining the two arrays 'prevLinks' and 'newLinks'.